# Can't understand why this program gives me this output. Please explain me

Tags: java, variables, static-variables

When I run this program it gives me the following output. Why I getting g.y as 2 not 5. So why I getting this output? What I missed to understand. Please explain me.

```
public class G {

   public  int x = 3; 
   public static int y = 7; 

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       G g = new G();
       G h = new G();

       g.x=1;
       g.y=5;
       h.x=4;
       h.y=2;

       System.out.println("g.x="+g.x);    
       System.out.println("g.y="+g.y);
       System.out.println("h.x="+h.x);
       System.out.println("h.y="+h.y);

    } 
}
```

Output:

```
g.x=1
g.y=2
h.x=4
h.y=2
```

Comment: Why do you think that's the output?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis because he ran it?

Comment: @Cruncher My question was meant in a sense of : "What's your current understanding of the output?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables are one per entire class, not one per instance.

Both `g.y` and `h.y` (and `G.y`) refer to the same variable, so the last assignment wins, and the value is 2.

It is confusing to access a `static` variable via an instance of the class, but Java allows it.

Comment: So I should get as 7. then why I am getting as 2. Even I changed the static variable to some other values. But the result is 2.

Comment: Because you change the static variable to 2 after you change it to 5. It's like saying `y=5;y=2;` What's the value of `y` now?

Comment: @user2824612 No, you initialized to `7`, then you assigned it `5`, then you assigned it `2`.

Comment: Even via Class I accessed it. But the result is same

Comment: @user2824612 It doesn't matter how you access it, it's still static

Comment: @user2824612 the point he was making about referencing by class and not instance is that it's immediately obvious that you're talking about that same variable. `G.y` and `G.y` are obviously the same variable. But `g.y` and `h.y` are not obvious. It's good practice to always use class names when referencing static variables.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** Try to think about what's the use and the behavior of a static variable.

Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) :

> Fields that have the static modifier in their declaration are called
>   static fields or class variables. They are associated with the class,
>   rather than with any object. Every instance of the class shares a
>   class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory. Any object
>   can change the value of a class variable, but class variables can also
>   be manipulated without creating an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

because, y is static
so, first you assigned y=7.then 5 and finally 2.
first value over ride to 5 then again over rides to 2.now current y value is 2.
if you do not mention that value as static your output will be (g dot y=5)
and (h dot y=2)